# Getting Columns with differences in a DataTable

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

So currently there is code that is SQL that returns a table with the differences between two tables. So it returns a table that has only the rows with different data between the two tables. The tables are exactly the same just on different environments. I am wondering how I can return the column name that have different data in them from the DataTable that was loaded by the SQL?

Here is just a little snippet of where the DataTable gets filled:

```
crs.DataHasChanged = ChangeState.False;
//Compare data of two tables.
sql = "Select 'Source Diff' as CompareDiff, " + BuildColumns(colIncludes, "C1", textColName) + " From " + sourceServer + "." + sourceDB + ".dbo." + tableStateObj.TableName + " C1 ";
sql += "EXCEPT ";
sql += "Select 'Source Diff' as CompareDiff, " + BuildColumns(colIncludes, "C2", textColName) + " From " + destServer + "." + destDB + ".dbo." + tableStateObj.TableName + " C2 ";
sql += "UNION ";
sql += "Select 'Dest Diff' as CompareDiff, " + BuildColumns(colIncludes, "C2", textColName) + " From " + destServer + "." + destDB + ".dbo." + tableStateObj.TableName + " C2 ";
sql += "EXCEPT ";
sql += "Select 'Dest Diff' as CompareDiff, " + BuildColumns(colIncludes, "C1", textColName) + " From " + sourceServer + "." + sourceDB + ".dbo." + tableStateObj.TableName + " C1 ";
sql += "Order By 2,3";

ds = new DataSet();
using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, compareConnString))
{
    da.Fill(ds);
}
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    crs.DataHasChanged = ChangeState.True;
}
crs.DataChangeTable = ds.Tables[0];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was shown below is what helped me get on the right path, but here is the code that actually worked for me:

```
ds = new DataSet();
using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, compareConnString))
{
    da.Fill(ds);
}
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    int rowCount = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
    int rowsRemaining = rowCount;

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i+=2)
    {
        if (!(rowsRemaining == 1))
        {
            var row1 = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i];
            var row2 = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i + 1];

            if (row1[1].ToString() == row2[1].ToString())
            {
                foreach (DataColumn col in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
                {
                    if (col.ColumnName != "CompareDiff")
                    {
                        if (row1[col].ToString() != row2[col].ToString())
                        {
                            crs.ColumnsChanged.Add(col.ColumnName);
                        }
                     }
                  }
              }
          }

          rowsRemaining -= 2;
      }
```

Could probably refactor to make it more efficient, but I am happy with the results for now. Hopefully that will help anyone else who had this issue.

Comment: Good job! Easier when you know the ins and outs of what you're looking for!

Answer (score 0):

In order to know which column is different, you need to read through them. Seems like you have 4 unions? Comparing 2 columns C1 and C2. Ugh. The logic will need a while to figure out.

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    int rowCounts = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
    int atRowx = 0;
    foreach(DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows){
      atRowX ++;
      if(atRowX = rowCounts-1)
        break;
      //Idea is to read two rows at a time. For each difference, either with C1 or C2, two lines are created.
      If(rowCounts % 4 == 0){ //It found a multiple of two differences
        //Clear up your code to keep the C1 and C2 together or else get the logic for reading row 1 and row 4 in here.
        foreach(DataColumn column in ds.Tables[0].Columns){
          if(row[column] != row+1[column]) 
            Console.WriteLine(ds.Tables[0].Column.ColumnName + "\t");
      }else if(rowCounts % 2){ //It strictly found one difference
        foreach(DataColumn column in ds.Tables[0].Columns){
          if(row[column] != row+1[column]) 
            Console.WriteLine(ds.Tables[0].Column.ColumnName + "\t");
      }
    }
    crs.DataHasChanged = ChangeState.True;
}
```

Comment: This logic compares Row X to Row X+1 and iterate through each column comparing them. I'm assuming your rs returns at least two rows when a discrepancy is found.

Comment: This didn't work, but it did get me going on the right track. You can't do row+1 in a foreach loop. Also I had to take into consideration rows that were added. So there wasn't always an even number of rows. So I will post my answer below. Thank you for your help!